# Red hat visudo read logs for regular user

Tags: rhel, sudo

It is necessary to allow reading logs `/var/log/.*` by a regular user. I do according to the documentation. [This manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-sudo-access_configuring-basic-system-settings)

```
mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d/
visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/mikelogger
```

inside visudo

`mikelogger localhost.localdomain =  /usr/bin/tail /var/log/messages`

run

```
su mikelogger -
tail -f /var/log/messages

tail: cannot open '/var/log/messages' for reading: Permission denied
tail: no files remaining
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding things to a file in sudoers.d as you did gives that user the ability to run the command specified using `sudo`.

Try this:

```
su mikelogger -
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
```

You will be prompted for the `mikelogger` user's password and upon successfully authenticating using the password the tail command should execute properly.

Comment: Thanks! I have a suspicion that the documentation is not written correctly, because an error occurs you are not in the group sudoers, but with this configuration it works `mikelogger ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/messages`